# How to integrate Service Now in jenkins pipeline script?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, servicenow

I have to tried to integrate Service now with jenkins. i have installed the Service Now plugin https://github.com/jenkinsci/service-now-plugin/blob/master/README.md in my environment. I need to get incident ticket using the jenkins pipeline script

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
pipeline{
    agent any
    stages {
        stage("BUILD"){
            steps{
                node('master') {
                    script {
                        def response = serviceNow_getCTask serviceNowConfiguration: [instance: 'dev7xx0'], credentialsId: '105ff3e8-7c1a-49c7-a514-4727xxx7f8c', serviceNowItem: [sysId: '965c9e5347c12200e0ef563dbbxxxx6'],vaultConfiguration: [url: 'https://dev79850.service-now.com']
                          echo response.content
                        def ctaskResponse = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response.content)
                        echo ctaskResponse.result[0]
                        def ctaskNumber = ctaskResponse.result[0].number
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the result of your attempted code?

Comment: It shows a "null" value